# Why is there an ANSI escape sequence for the Fraktur font?

Tags: ansi-escape

I was browsing Wikipedia's [handy list of ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) when I noticed that `\33[20m` is the escape sequence for *Fraktur*, a blackletter font. The escape sequence has the annotation, *hardly ever used*. Why even have this escape sequence in the first place though? The font isn't even monospace. Is this an easter egg?

Comment: The `SGR` codes were designed by a committee.  Presumably someone on the committee thought that Fraktur deserved as much attention as Italics.  However, no one seems to recall the circumstances.

Comment: Reiterating: Fraktur was a popular font used for *German* text.  Italics were named for their origin: [*Italian*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/198435/italian-vs-italic).  The `SGR 20` which you asked about is not "ANSI", but ISO -- the focus of standardization shifting to Europe.

Comment: That said: italics do serve a very specific purpose in languages other than Italian, that is, to emphasize certain phrases in a context where bold isn't appropriate. For that reason we have italic variants of common fonts, including many monospace fonts. Fraktur isn't monospace, and doesn't serve any specific purpose outside of German (that I know of; I'm admittedly surprised that it's even used enough in German to justify including it).

Comment: As I said "designed by a committee".  Also recall that ISO-6429 was first published in 1976, while the fifth edition (e.g., the last) was published in 1991.  Because Italics are encoded with 3, and Fraktur with 20, it is reasonable to suppose that Frakur may not have been in the initial revision, and was added to achieve someone's notion of equal treatment.

Comment: I'm more interested in knowing what terminal emulators out there actually support Fraktur characters... there's [Terminology](https://github.com/billiob/terminology), but I haven't been able to get it running on Mac OS (it seems Linux-specific). If anybody can screencap for my curious little eyes how Fraktur text looks on it, that'd be awesome. #obsessed-typophile

Comment: @Alhadis - https://fau.re/blog/20140406_terminology_fraktur.html has a couple of examples of fraktur in Terminology

Comment: [**Mintty**](https://mintty.github.io/) seems to support it (and a couple of odd things also).